# Testing method that returns relation model attribute

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have the following models:

```
class Course(Base):

    title = models.CharField('Título', max_length=200)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_category(self):
        return self.subcategory.category


class SubCategory(Base):
    title = models.CharField('Título', max_length=80)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Category(Base):
    title = models.CharField('Título', max_length=80)
```

How can I test the get_category method?

I'm trying to do that but the test don't pass on coverage report.

Comment: Share what did you try please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
class CourseModelTest(TestCase):
    def test_get_category(self):
        category = CategoryFactory()
        subcategory = SubCategoryFactory(category=category)
        course = CourseFactory(subcategory=subcategory)

        self.assertEqual(course.get_category().id, category.id)
```

Comment: My fault. I'm not calling the function to test. 
Thank you taras.